# Date function not correct

Tags: php, mysql, date

ok so i have this function to when i post it will take the exact time i post and save it in the database ... i call on that date for my post, when it was actually posted. but the problem is it says the wrong time , it has the date right and the year , but not the time. its about 8 hours ahead of my time . here is the code im using

To post into the database.

```
$date1 = time();
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO photos 
SET photo='$newname', title='$title', date='$date', author='$by'")
```

And This is where i call on it.

```
$date = date("F j, Y, g:i a", $row['date']);
```

Comment: Check your php timezone setting and date format for inserting it into mysql.

Comment: where do i look for that?

Comment: Obligatory: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: well i turn $date1 into $date before i put it into the database

Comment: code takes server time. You need to set timezone settings. Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 0):

make the 'date' field in your mysql as "**datetime**" and run the query as ...."**date = now()**".... (i.e. use the built-in mysql datetime function).

> INSERT INTO photos 
>   SET photo='$newname', title='$title', date=now(), author='$by'

Also, keep in mind the timezone difference between your pc and the server..

Take care

Answer (score 0):

You need to set time zone to get the required time. e.g. you can set time zone in php as following
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

Answer (score 0):

you can use time stamp data type with Current_timestamp   which will take less space for storage

means something like

**insert into** photos(photo,title,date,author) **values**('$newname','$title',current_timestamp,'$by');

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to insert your current time then you must use javascript to attain that. If that is what you want I can code that for you.